# Sufficient condition for subgroup being normal

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm unsure of how to solve the following.

> Let $p: E\rightarrow B$ be a covering map and $p(e_0)=b_0$. Show that
>   $H_0:=p_\ast(\pi_1(E, e_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B, b_0)$
>   if every pair of points $e_1, e_2$ of $p^{-1}(b_0)$, there is an
>   equivalence $h: E\rightarrow E$ with $h(e_1)=e_2$.

Suppose that  for every pair of points $e_1, e_2$ of $p^{-1}(b_0)$, there is an equivalence $h: E\rightarrow E$ with $h(e_1)=e_2$. Let $e_1\ne e_0$ and consider $\pi_1(E, e_1)$. By assumption $g(e_1)=e_0$ for some equivalence $g:E\rightarrow E$. Hence $g_\ast(\pi_1(E, e_1))=\pi_1(E,e_0)$ and $p\circ g = p$. By the general lifting lemma, it follows that ... **This is where I'm unsure.**

Any help would be appreciated.