# Show that $H_0=p_*(\pi_1(E,e_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ if and only if for every pair of pint $e_1, e_2$ of $p^{-1}(b_0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

[image]

I have a post about this here [Sufficient condition for subgroup being normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292357/sufficient-condition-for-subgroup-being-normal) but it has no answer, I would like to know how to solve this problem.

I have thought that I can use the following theorem:

[image]

Taking into account the theorem, if we assume that $p_*(\pi_1(E,e_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B, b_0)$, it is sufficient to show that given $e_1, e_2\in p^{-1}(b_0)$ then $p_*(\pi_1(E,e_1))=p_*(\pi_1(E,e_2))$, to do this let's take $[\alpha]\in p_*(\pi_1(E,e_1))$, let's see that $[\alpha]\in p_*(\pi_1(E,e_2))$, as $[\alpha]\in p_*(\pi_1(E,e_1))$ then $[p\circ \gamma]=[\alpha]$ for some loop $\gamma$ in $E$ based on $e_1$ , I want to prove that there is a loop $\delta$ in $E$ based on $e_2$ such that $[p\circ \delta]=[\alpha]$ but I do not know how to do this, could someone help me please? I've thought about solving this problem by taking a path $\beta$ in $E$ from $e_2$ to $e_1$ since $E$ is arc-connected, so $[\beta*\gamma*\bar{\beta}]$ is a loop in $E$ based on $e_2$, but I do not know what else to do.

How can I do the other direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well $p\circ \beta$ is then a loop in $B$ based at $b_0$

Comment: @Max 
Yes, but what I need is a loop $[\delta]$ in $E$ based on $e_2$ so that $[p\circ \delta]=[\alpha]$, How can I do this?

Comment: $p\circ (\beta * \gamma * \overline{\beta}) = (p\circ\beta)*(p\circ\gamma)*(p\circ\overline{\beta}) = (p\circ\beta)*(p\circ\gamma)*(p\circ\beta)^{-1}$

Comment: @Max What does it do for me?